# Convert python tuples to Google Maps json coordinates

Tags: python, json, google-maps, tuples, coordinates

I'm having a little trouble understanding the order of operations to get my tuples converted to json. Here is my list:

```
coordinates = [(45.62, -122.23),(45.63, -122.22),(45.64, -122.21)]
```

When running it through my code:

```
coordinates = [(45.62, -122.23),(45.63, -122.22),(45.64, -122.21)]    
coordinatesList = json.dumps(dict(coordinates))
```

I manage to get a single json array. Here is my current output:

```
print(coordinatesList)

{"45.62": -122.23, "45.63": -122.22, "45.64": -122.21}
```

As you can see, I'm having multiple issues here. Some coordinates are encapsulated with quotes while the second values aren't. I also need to append the values with "lat" and "lng" to fit Google Maps api, but am confused about where in the flow control to do so.

Here is my desired output:

```
       [
          {lat: 45.62, lng: -122.23},
          {lat: 45.63, lng: -122.22},
          {lat: 45.64, lng: -122.21},
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json keys have to be string, so in double quotes.

You could reorganize your data using a list comprehension to generate the list of dicts with proper keys, and if you want to remove the quotes, just use `str.replace`

```
import json

coordinates = [(45.62, -122.23),(45.63, -122.22),(45.64, -122.21)]

result = json.dumps([{"lat":x[0],"lng":x[1]} for x in coordinates],indent=2).replace('"',"")
```

which gives me (thanks to prettying `indent` parameter):

```
[
  {
    lat: 45.62,
    lng: -122.23
  },
  {
    lat: 45.63,
    lng: -122.22
  },
  {
    lat: 45.64,
    lng: -122.21
  }
]
```

in that simple case, you have more control without `json` using just `str.format` and `str.join`:

```
result = "[\n{}\n]".format(",\n".join("  {{lat: {},lng: {}}}".format(*x) for x in coordinates))
```

result:

```
[
  {lat: 45.62,lng: -122.23},
  {lat: 45.63,lng: -122.22},
  {lat: 45.64,lng: -122.21}
]
```

EDIT: if your input is actually a *string*:

```
coordinates = "[(45.62, -122.23),(45.63, -122.22),(45.64, -122.21)]"
```

you can use `ast.literal_eval` to safely evaluate it to a python list of tuples:

```
import ast
coordinates = ast.literal_eval(coordinates)
```

and the code above applies.

Comment: result = "[\n{}\n]".format(",\n".join("  {{lat: {},lng: {}}}".format(*x) for x in coordinates))
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Getting that error?

Comment: not with the sample data you provided, and which I pasted. happens if one of the tuples has only 1 value in it.

Comment: Ah the coordinates list is actually being stored as a string, like coordinates = "[(45.62, -122.23),(45.63, -122.22)". How would I convert it back to literal for your solution to work?

Comment: you mean `coordinates = "[(45.62, -122.23),(45.63, -122.22),(45.64, -122.21)]"` ?

Comment: Yes, that is how its being retrieved from the database, stored as a string. I assume this is why I am getting an error from your solution.

Comment: check my edit but in that case how can you get a valid result? your question doesn't mention that input is as string...

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the list of coordinate pairs and convert them to JSON:

```
coordinates = [(45.62, -122.23),(45.63, -122.22),(45.64, -122.21)]
coord_list = []
for coord_pair in coordinates:
    json_coord_pair = {}
    json_coord_pair["lat"] = str(coord_pair[0])
    json_coord_pair["lng"] = str(coord_pair[1])
    json_coord_pair = json.dumps(json_coord_pair)
    coord_list.append(json_coord_pair)
```

Comment: json_coord_pair["lng"] = str(coord_pair[1])
IndexError: string index out of range
?

Comment: try copying and pasting my example. I just did and it works.